# can I return an address from a contract interface instead of another contract?

Tags: solidity, dapps, addresses

for example i have a contract function that returns a contract, can I define an interface that calls that function, but only returns an address?

```
contract foo {
   ....
   ....
}

contract bar {
   function getFoo() returns (foo);
}
```

Can I make an interface for bar that just returns an address instead of foo? like so:

```
contract barInterface {
   function getFoo() returns (address);
}
```

I can't change bar itself because it's a pre-existing contract

Answer (score 0):

... returns (address f) {
  return address(foo);
}

Hope it helps.